# How does SmsMessage work in the Kotlin library?

Tags: android, kotlin, sms, symbols

I don't understand how this class works when receiving new sms messages.

My problem is that if there is a "#" sign in the SMS body, then the first part of the message gets into `getDisplayMessageBody()`, and the second part of the message gets into `getMessageBody()`.

What do I need to do to receive everything in one?
It seems to me that it somehow works strangely, although it is designed for SMS.

> Example of received sms: Some text works #100 percent

If I read only getMessageBody(), I will get the following text:

> #100 percent

And in get "getDisplayMessageBody()" will be stored:

> Some text works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're describing might be due to the way SMS messages are constructed, especially when special characters like "#" are involved.

SMS messages may have two parts: the user data header (UDH) and the user data. The UDH is typically used for things like concatenating multiple SMS messages into one or for indicating special formatting in messages.

getMessageBody() and getDisplayMessageBody() in SmsMessage class may have different behaviour:

1. ***getMessageBody***(): This method returns the user data part of the SMS, which includes the text message itself. In your example, it correctly returns "#100 percent" because that's the content of the user data.
2. ***getDisplayMessageBody***(): This method returns the displayable part of the SMS, which is usually the content of the SMS that's meant to be shown to the user. In your example, it returns "Some text works" because the UDH or any special formatting is stripped out, and this is the part of the SMS that's typically displayed to the user.

so i think if you want to receive the entire message, you have to concatenate these both:

In Kotlin:

```
val fullMessage = smsMessage.displayMessageBody + smsMessage.messageBody
```

In Java:

```
String fullMessage = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody() + smsMessage.getMessageBody();
```